# jQuery | Ajax | json : looping through not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This was working all fine until I decided to tidy up my code.  Now i've tried so many things i don't even know it was originally.

here is my json response.

```
 Array
(
    [26892] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 26892
            [subject] => LAST DAY 
            [mailbox] => abc
            [date] => Oct 1
            [host] => sstock.com
        )

    [5418] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 5418
        [subject] => ENJOY
        [mailbox] => abc
        [date] => Feb 8
        [host] => stock.com
    )

   [5178] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 5178
        [subject] => SUPER 
        [mailbox] => box1
        [date] => Feb 6
        [host] => stock.com
    )
```

here is what the messy code looks like now.

```
var htmlStr = '';
  $.ajax({ 
      url: 'data.php',
     data: {data: 'nz-json', from_mailbox: mailbox, from_host: host},
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
     beforeSend: function(){

          $('.nz-getnewz-spinner').show();
       },
     success: function(output) {

      $.each(output, function(k, v) {
        htmlStr += '<div  from-host="'+v.host+'">'+v.mailbox+'</div>';
      });

      $('.nz-getnewz-spinner').hide();
      $('#output-div').html(htmlStr);
        if (uid === undefined) {
           // do stuff
        } else {
          //do other stuff
        } 
     }

  });
```

Since ive been playing with it all day ive been getting different js errors, but it all started with this error.

I suspect my json response structure is done poorly.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in
```

Im close to just rewriting it all from scratch, but before i do that i was hoping somoene could point out any obvious issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Start with basic debugging, in the `success` function add `console.log(typeof output, output)` and see what you get

Comment: Will get on that right away.  I have been trying to debug but havent thought of 'typeof'.  Thanks

Comment: JSON response? Where? check php,  json_encode to serialize it

Comment: so its working now.  Wow. wish i posted here hours ago.  The changes i made were.  1.  removed <pre></pre> .   2. and the php function that generated the json response had ... return json_decode($list);.. i moved the decode step to the function that ECHOs the response.

Comment: Great! Add and accept your own answer